# Jquery : how to order elements while adding them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an user list

```
<div id="userList">
</div>
```

Where I do add dom/html elements such as:

```
<div data-name="john" data-gender="m">john</div>
<div data-name="alan" data-gender="m">alan></div>
<div data-name="mike" data-gender="m">mike</div>
<div data-name="jennifer" data-gender="f">jennifer</div>
<div data-name="sandy" data-gender="f">sandy</div>
```

How would I add them so they are sorted by gender first and then by name

so the final output would be:

```
jennifer
sandy
alan
john
mike
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

it's just a `sort`. we can know that from your question:

1. if `gender` is the same, sort by name
2. otherwise, female first

so this is the code

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('userList');
  var divs = [].slice.call(ul.children);
  [].sort.call(divs, (a,b) => {
   var genderA = a.getAttribute('data-gender');
   var genderB = b.getAttribute('data-gender');
   var nameA = a.getAttribute('data-name');
   var nameB = b.getAttribute('data-name');
   if (genderA === genderB) {
    // console.log(nameA < nameB)
    return nameA < nameB ? -1 : (nameA > nameB ? 1 : 0);
   }
   // console.log(genderA == 'f' ? -1 : 1)
   return genderA == 'f' ? -1 : 1;
  });
  console.log(divs);
```

```html
 original: 
 <ul id="userList">
  <div data-name="john" data-gender="m">john</div>
  <div data-name="alan" data-gender="m">alan</div>
  <div data-name="mike" data-gender="m">mike</div>
  <div data-name="jennifer" data-gender="f">jennifer</div>
  <div data-name="sandy" data-gender="f">sandy</div>
 </ul>
 <hr>
 sorted:
 see Console
```